# Should we have a tag for the coupon collector's problem?

Tags: discussion, tags

The coupon collector's problem is a [well-known example in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Searching the site for [`coupon is:question`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+is%3Aquestion) suggests we have about a dozen posts on it, but that searching is complicated because we have e.g. some business/marketing questions where "coupons" turn up in the retailing context.

It strikes me that `[coupon-collector-problem]` or `[coupon-collectors-problem]` (that looks grammatically shoddy but I don't think you can have possessive apostrophe in a tag name?) or maybe just `[coupon-problem]` might justabout be justified to tie these related questions together. Or is this too few to be worth doing?

(When we had fewer it would have been much easier to pick them out from search results. My personal inclination is we now have enough, and searching is somewhat muddied by other uses of "coupon", that it's justified to start a new tag.)

Comment: I created the tag and tagged a couple of the oldest and most pertinent questions.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. I think [`[coupon-collector-problem]`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coupon-collector-problem) was probably the best choice of name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. If something deserves an article in Wikipedia, it deserves a tag too.

Comment: But it would be good if you write a wiki excerpt for this tag & apply it to other relevant questions, @Silverfish.

Comment: I plan to drip feed some other questions into it

Comment: I think there probably is a minimum number of threads criterion as well, but "has a wikipedia entry" is an interesting approach. Hadn't thought of it that way but can see the logic

Comment: I unilaterally made a tag for the Hauck-Donner effect a while back, and the move appears to have been accepted by the community. I don't see why we can't do the same here.

Comment: [I have written a wiki and excerpt now](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/coupon-collector-problem/info). Thanks for the suggestion.